# Ruby conditional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, erb

In ruby what's a nice way of choosing which array to traverse conditionally?

If condition is true -> use array 1 if not use array B.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
   <% if  @post.active ?  %>
        <% Post::A_OPTIONS.each do |option|  %>
    <%else %>
        <% Post::B_OPTIONS.each do |option| %>
    <%end%>
      <br><%= radio_button_tag 'option', option, @option == option %>
      <%= option.humanize %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your business logic into your model. such as

```
class Post
  def options
    active ? Post::A_OPTIONS : Post::B_OPTIONS
  end
end
```

then in your view,

```
<% @post.options.each do |option| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'option', option, @option == option %>
  <%= option.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

In this case, your view is isolated from how the options are generated, and both **options logic** and **view logic** are simple and clean

Comment: As you are in the `Post` class, you can simplify with: `self.active ? A_OPTIONS : B_OPTIONS`

Comment: You shouldn't need the `self` either.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```rb
<% (@post.active ? Post::A_OPTIONS : Post::B_OPTIONS).each do |option|  %>
  <br><%= radio_button_tag 'option', option, @option == option %>
  <%= option.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you define a method on the `Post` model that simply returns the correct options? e.g.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  A_OPTIONS = [...];
  B_OPTIONS = [...];

  # other stuff

  def options
    if active
      A_OPTIONS
    else
      B_OPTIONS
    end
  end
end
```

And then your view will be dead simple:

```
<% @post.options.each do |option|  %>
  <br><%= radio_button_tag 'option', option, @option == option %>
  <%= option.humanize %>
<% end %>
```